# How to fix webview has been removed from react native it can now be install and imported from react-native-webview instead of react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, Button, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Chart from "react-native-f2chart";
import { WebView } from "react-native";
import { Container, Title } from "../components";
import { basePie, labelPie } from "./scripts";

type Props = {};

class PieChartScreen extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Container>
          <View>
            <Title title="基础饼图" />

            <View style={{ height: 250 }}>
              <Chart initScript={basePie} webView={WebView} />
            </View>
          </View>

          <View>
            <Title title="带文本饼图" />

            <View style={{ height: 350 }}>
              <Chart initScript={labelPie} webView={WebView} />
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={{ height: 20 }} />
        </Container>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default PieChartScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario Old WebView is now deprecated for better performance and to reduce package sizes. You can find more information about this by [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html)

**Solution**

Install new WebView Package using this command

```
npm install --save react-native-webview
```

You can find more information regarding package installation from [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md)

After installing above mentioned package now remove old imports and re-import WebView like this

```
import { WebView, } from 'react-native'; //Remove this from your imports

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'; //Add this to your imports
```

Your final code should look like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Chart from "react-native-f2chart";
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';  // New changed import
import { Container, Title } from "../components";
import { basePie, labelPie } from "./scripts";

type Props = {}; class PieChartScreen extends PureComponent {

render() {

return (

  <ScrollView>

    <Container>

      <View>

        <Title title="基础饼图" />

        <View style={{ height: 250 }}>

          <Chart initScript={basePie} webView={WebView} />

        </View>
      </View>

      <View>
        <Title title="带文本饼图" />
          <Chart initScript={labelPie} webView={WebView} />

        </View>

      </View>

      <View style={{ height: 20 }} />

    </Container>

  </ScrollView>

);
}

}

export default PieChartScreen;
```

However you can find all the information about new WebView from [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)