# Invariant violation react-native-webview

Tags: react-native

Firstly I installed react-native-webview . i didn't link it because it links automatically . But it doesn't work . I tried with cleaning gradlew.bat file in android . Although that It didn't work . Can anyone help me ? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a library (`react-native-qrcode`) which is no longer 
being maintained, according to their GitHub which you can find here:

https://github.com/cssivision/react-native-qrcode#readme

The library is still using WebView which used to be a part of core `react-native` library, but has since been removed. It is no longer compatible with newer versions of `react-native`.

As an alternative suggestion, I'd like to point you towards `react-native-qrcode-scanner` which is still being maintained and has about 12000 weekly downloads from NPM alone. This should prove to be more compatible with current React Native versions, also more stable going forward:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-scanner

Comment: I have a problem that is relating to the react-native-webview

Comment: No, read the stack trace. `react-native-qrcode` is using `react-native`'s webview under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

**Hey, I have posted a full answer regarding this issue on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073079/how-to-fix-webview-has-been-removed-from-react-native-it-can-now-be-install-and/60107262#60107262) .**

---

For your scenario Old WebView is now deprecated for better performance and to reduce package sizes. You can find more information about this by [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md)

Install new WebView Package using this command

```
npm install --save react-native-webview
```

After installing above mentioned package now remove old imports and re-import WebView like this

```
import { WebView, } from 'react-native'; //Remove this from your imports

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'; //Add this to your imports
```